# polymer iron-selector for rows of table

Tags: html, polymer

I would like to use `<iron-selector>` to select rows of my table, but it seems to behave strangely.

This (obviously) works:

```
<iron-selector selected="0">
  <div>Item 0</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</iron-selector>
```

But if I want to have selectable rows in a table, neither with divs in the table:

```
<table>          
  <tr>
    <td>Item 0</td><td>bar</td><td>flan</td>
  </tr>
  <iron-selector selected="0">
    <div>
        <tr>
        <td>item 1</td><td>bard</td><td>fladn</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td>item 2</td><td>bard</td><td>fladn</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
   </iron-selector>
  </table>
```

or without:

```
<table>      
 <iron-selector selected="0">
  <tr><td>Item 0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
</iron-selector>
```

works. Should I just make a table with divs? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here is invalid HTML. You can't have an `iron-selector` or a `div` as a child of a `table` element.

You could either make your table with multiple `div` elements as you say or you could create your own Polymer element that extends a `tbody` and uses the same behaviour as the `iron-selector`. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV8BvxpNQOs) is a tutorial for extending native elements. The docs for [iron-selector](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-selector) will tell you the behaviours it implements.

Here is an example of extending the `tbody` element and implementing the same behaviour that the `iron-selector` element uses:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selectable.html">

<dom-module id="selectable-table">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "selectable-table",
      extends: "tbody",
      behaviors: [
        Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior
      ]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

You can then use this by doing the following:

```
<table>
  <tbody is="selectable-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        item 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        item 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        item 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This gives you the following output (with styles added to show which item is selected):

[image: Demo of code above]

Comment: Thanks! I decided to abandon the tables go with div tables after reading some stuff about what tables were for.

Comment: And I switched back to tables since this turned out to be a better solution! Thanks again!